# Memory issue while generating matrix for recommendation system in python

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am  developing recommendation system using collaborative filtering using python, panda dataframe and NumPy array to create matrices. Application is running fine with 1000 user base, but when running with 20k+ data, its throwing memory issue while generating matrix size of 20k*20k. Please help me in solving the issue.

```
user_test_level_12 = pd.DataFrame(squareform(pdist(user_test_12.ix[:, 1:])), columns=user_test_12.student_id, index=user_test_12.student_id
```

)

Comment: what are you trying to do with your data

Comment: I am trying to calculate the pairwise distance of the Student details, which are mapping to each other and then trying to multiply the student details * co-relation matrix of the student course completed details.

Comment: can you show with an small example, may be for a 5*5 data

Answer (score 1):

20K x 20K is way too big of a matrix to get using only CPU memory. That's why you get MemoryError.

I'd suggest using either batches (each time calculate a smal part of the matrix) and add them all together, if you really need all at once.

The second option would be using a sparse matrix. I assume most of your data is sparse as it is a recommender system. A sparse matrix can save you both memory and computational time.

Without seeing the code or knowing your intention that's the best I can think of.

Comment: 20k x 20k is 400M right? Times 4 bytes per a float, we're at 1.6G. That's quite some memory but not really "way too big", is it?